# Posicionar dos elementos adaptables al ancho de la pantalla

Tags: html, css

En un contenedor principal tengo dos *div*, en el cuál trato que ambos elementos sean adaptables a la pantalla. Hasta ahora solo el último *div* se adapta, pero el primero no lo hace.

He intentado ponerle *flex* al contenedor principal, para que los *div* hijos se puedan adaptar, pero hasta ahora obtengo el mismo resultado.

Gracias de antemano.

Acá dejo mi código:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#principal {
    background: skyblue;
    /*display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;*/
}

#principal #contenedor-1 .column ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#principal #contenedor-1 {
    border: 1px solid navy;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#principal #contenedor-2 {
    background: skyblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#principal #contenedor-2 div {
    border: 2px solid navy;
    width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="principal">
    <div id="contenedor-1">
        <div class="column">
            <span>Título 1</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1 Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 1 Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 1 Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 1 Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 1 Item 1</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <span>Título 2</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 2 Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 2 Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 2 Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 2 Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 2 Item 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <span>Título 3</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 3 Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 3 Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 3 Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 3 Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 3 Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contenedor-2">
        <div>
            <p>Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cambia el width de 800px por max-width 800px o por flex: 0 0 [Algún valor en %]. Las columnas en pantallas pequeñas se pegan unas a otras yo le pondría un width a las columnas con media query

Comment: solo cambia el tamaño fijo por un `max-width: 800px;` te recomiendo que uses bootstrap en estos casos para hacer estas cosas mas rápido y también tener todo mas optimizado, te dejo este [enlace](https://getbootstrap.com/) si te interesa aplicarlo, saludos y suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió perfecto. Pero me entró la duda del por qué el `max-width` se adapta al ancho cuándo se reduce la pantalla, ya que no se supone que el `max-width` solo sirve para indicar el tamaño máximo del elemento?.

Answer (score 0):

Añade esto a tu css

```
#principal #contenedor-1 ,
#principal #contenedor-2 {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#principal {
    background: skyblue;
    /*display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;*/
}

#principal #contenedor-1 .column ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#principal #contenedor-1 {
    border: 1px solid navy;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#principal #contenedor-2 {
    background: skyblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#principal #contenedor-2 div {
    border: 2px solid navy;
    width: 800px;
}

/* Añadido a tu código */
#principal #contenedor-1 ,
#principal #contenedor-2 {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="principal">
    <div id="contenedor-1">
        <div class="column">
            <span>Título 1</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1 Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 1 Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 1 Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 1 Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 1 Item 1</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <span>Título 2</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 2 Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 2 Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 2 Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 2 Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 2 Item 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <span>Título 3</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 3 Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 3 Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 3 Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 3 Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 3 Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contenedor-2">
        <div>
            <p>Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Debes explicar qué hace el código y cómo resuelve el problema. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código sin una descripción apropiada se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor, añade más detalles para extender tu respuesta. Lee [answer] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

espero te sea de utilidad el siguiente codigo:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#contenedor-1{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column{
  background: skyblue;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

#principal #contenedor-1 .column ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#principal #contenedor-1 {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#principal #contenedor-2 {
    background: skyblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#principal #contenedor-2 div {
    border: 2px solid navy;
    width: 50%;
}

#contenedor-2{
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#contenedor-2 div p{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="principal">
    <div id="contenedor-1">
        <div class="column">
            <span>Título 1</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1 Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 1 Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 1 Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 1 Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 1 Item 1</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <span>Título 2</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 2 Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 2 Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 2 Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 2 Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 2 Item 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <span>Título 3</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 3 Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 3 Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 3 Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 3 Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 3 Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contenedor-2">
        <div>
            <p>Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```